# Splitting an array of tuples while keeping both as arrays

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I have an array of tuples, and I was hoping to split the elements in the tuple apart, while keeping both sides of the tuple in a separate array.

I'm new to Python, so I don't know if this question has an obvious solution.

```
arr = [(1,4), (2,4)]

'''some code'''
arr1 = [1,2]
arr2 = [4,4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using zip is quite nice, with the expansion operator *:

```
arr = [(1, 4), (2, 4)]

a = [*zip(*arr)]
b = [list(i) for i in zip(*arr)]

print(a)
# [(1, 2), (4, 4)]

print(b)
# [[1, 2], [4, 4]]
```

especially if you don't need the result as lists

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is with a pair of *list comprehensions*

```
arr1 = [t[0] for t in arr]
arr2 = [t[1] for t in arr]
```

This approach would be better if you actually had more than two items in the tuples, because you could do it in a loop.  List comprehensions can seem confusing at first, but they're quite powerful.

Another way is a good, old-fashioned *for loop*.

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
for first, second in arr:
    arr1.append(first)
    arr2.append(second)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's convenient to iterate over an array of tuples like so:

```py
arr1 = []
arr2 = []

for x, y in arr:
    arr1.append(x)
    arr2.append(y)
```

Each element of `arr` is a tuple with two elements, so this destructures the tuple to the variables `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Python list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for this:

```
arr1 = [x[0] for x in arr]
arr2 = [x[1] for x in arr]
```

Basically what this does is that for each tuple `x` in `arr`, it adds the first tuple element (`x[0]`) to `arr1`, similarly for `arr2`.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to use the function `zip`.

```
arr = [(1,4), (2,4)]
res = list(zip(*arr))  #  res = [(1, 2), (4, 4)]
arr1 = res[0] # arr1 = (1, 2)
arr2 = res[1] # arr2 = (4,4)
```

This might be more convenient than the classic for loop when you have list with more elements.

Comment: This produces tuples, but the question asked for lists.